# g++ error no such file or directory

Tags: c++, bash, unix

I keep getting this error when I try to compile a `.cpp` file in my unix terminal.

Here is my command:

```
-bash-4.2$ g++ -o test.cpp test
```

Output:

```
g++: error: test: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

But, when I type in `ls`:

```
test.cpp
```

Do I have the wrong version of g++?

Comment: You've mixed up the order of arguments. `-o` takes the output file you want to create, but you seem to pass your source code. The compiler treats `test` as the source code (input file). Change your command line to `g++ -o test test.cpp`. If you're lucky it bailed out before overwriting your source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command line is wrong. Try this

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

The syntax is `-o <output-file>`, but you had your input file listed there, so g++ was looking for `test` as an input file.

Comment: That was what I put down for my arguments.

Comment: Based on your error message, this I clearly the problem. Please don't waste people'people's time with bogus questions  - *copy and paste* your inputs and outputs.